# PHP inserting image and video into one mysql record

Tags: php, mysql

I am successfully able to insert an image and video file to my mysql database, but it is creating 2 records.  My belief is because of my "Type" field, it's not able to create 2 different values for the same record, so I created "Type" and "Type2" thinking that would solve the issue.  It created the same "Image/png" value.
Here is my form script:

```
<form action="saveimage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5"      cellpadding="5">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Picture:</td><td><input name="rpic" type="file" accept="image/*"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Video:</td><td><input name="rvideo" type="file" accept="video/*"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

This is the script for inserting the files:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

function GetImageExtension($rpic)
{
    if(empty($rpic)) return false;
    switch($rpic)
    {
        case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
        case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
        case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
        case 'image/png': return '.png';
        default: return false;
    }
}
function GetVideoExtension($rvideo)
{
    if(empty($rvideo)) return false;
    switch($rvideo)
    {
        case 'video/asf': return '.asf';
        case 'video/avi': return '.avi';
        case 'video/wmv': return '.wmv';
        default: return false;
    }
}
if (!empty($_FILES["rpic"]["name"]))
{
    $file_name=$_FILES["rpic"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["rpic"]["tmp_name"];
    $type=$_FILES["rpic"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($type);
    $name=$_FILES["rpic"]["name"];
    $path = "uploads/".$name;

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $path))
{
    $query_upload="INSERT into recipes (type, rpic, path, posted) VALUES ('".$type."','".$rpic."','".$path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("Error in $query_upload == ----->".mysql_error());
} else {
    exit("Error while uploading your file.");
    }
}
if (!empty($_FILES["rvideo"]["name"]))
{
    $file_name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["tmp_name"];
    $type=$_FILES["rvideo"]["type"];
    $ext= GetVideoExtension($type2);
    $name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["name"];
    $path = "uploads/".$name;
    $pathvideo = "uploads/".$name;

if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $pathvideo))
{
    $query_upload="INSERT into recipes (type, rvideo, pathvideo, posted) VALUES ('".$type."','".$rvideo."','".$pathvideo."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("Error in $query_upload == ----->".mysql_error());
} else {
    exit("Error while uploading your file.");
    }
}
?>
```

Any help that anyone could provide would be appreciated.  Again, I would prefer to only have one record created.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are inserting both the Photo & Video at same-time, In meantime you need to do both
 Validation & Db insertion. So,use the flag concept to attain this,

// flag declaration
                        $flag_Photo=0;
                        $flag_Video=0;

```
                    if (!empty($_FILES["rpic"]["name"]))
                    {
                        $file_name=$_FILES["rpic"]["name"];
                        $temp_name=$_FILES["rpic"]["tmp_name"];
                        $type=$_FILES["rpic"]["type"];
                        $ext= GetImageExtension($type);
                        $name=$_FILES["rpic"]["name"];
                        $path = "uploads/".$name;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $path))
                    {
                      $flag_Photo=1;  
                    } 
                    else {
                        $flag_Photo=0;
                        //exit("Error while uploading your file.");
                        }
                    }
                    if (!empty($_FILES["rvideo"]["name"]))
                    {
                        $file_name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["name"];
                        $temp_name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["tmp_name"];
                        $type=$_FILES["rvideo"]["type"];
                        $ext= GetVideoExtension($type2);
                        $name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["name"];
                        $path = "uploads/".$name;
                        $pathvideo = "uploads/".$name;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $pathvideo))
                    {
                    $flag_Video=1; 

                    } else {
                        $flag_Video=0;
                        }
                    }
                    if($flag_Photo ==1 && $flag_Video==1)
                    {
                     $query_upload="INSERT into recipes (type, rpic, path, rvideo, pathvideo,  
                        posted) VALUES
```

('".$type."','".$rpic."','".$path."','".$rvideo."','".$pathvideo."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
                            mysql_query($query_upload) or die("Error in $query_upload == ----->".mysql_error());
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            exit("Error while uploading your file.");
                         }

Comment: I used the code that you supplied, but still only one "Type" was entered which was the rvideo type and path. The path field had no record inserted.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: UPDATE: After changing the "Type" in the rvideo coding to "Type2," both the video and image mime types have been inserted to the table. Now, only the name (rpic and rvideo) need fixing; they are both showing the rvideo value.

Comment: Much Better.. the same
    In Photo , $name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["name"];

    In Video,  $name=$_FILES["rvideo"]["name"]; 
 
   Please change this as you did for type.. It will Work then.   
   Cheers!..

Comment: Cheers!  It is working now.  I had to remove the "$path" line from the rvideo coding, but it's all good now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use INSERT you create a new row. If you want just one row use just one SQL query or use an UPDATE query:

```
INSERT into recipes (type, rpic, rvideo, pathvideo, posted) VALUES (...)
```

You have to re arrange your logic or use an UPDATE on the second query. Something like this:

```
UPDATE recipes SET rvideo = $val WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did try just 1 insert statement prior to my code above, but since the rpic (image) field came before rvideo (video file), the type field displayed image/png for the mime type for rvideo.